# Secure credentials in config.json file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, credentials, config.json

I have a config.json file which contains my db credentials. It has local, dev, qa and prod.
Something like below:-

```
{
"production": {
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "database": "dbname",
        "schema": "schema",
        "host": "hostname",
        "dialect": "postgres",
        "port": 5432,
        "logging": false,
        "EncryptionKey": "ekey"
    },
   "development": {
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "database": "dbname",
        "schema": "schema",
        "host": "hostname",
        "dialect": "postgres",
        "port": 5432,
        "logging": false,
        "EncryptionKey": "ekey"
    }
}
```

Having the credentials in plain text is a risk and I want to mitigate it. I don't want to use .gitignore or some credentials manager like AWS secret manager. Is there any other way around?